# Angular - page title based on route and component data

Tags: angular, angular-router

Angular 7 btw.

I'm trying to set a custom title for each route, but some of the titles require information that only the routed component has (i.e the route contains the user id but the title should contain the user name).

I initially went into every routed component and set the title (using [Title.setTitle()](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title#settitle)) in `ngOnInit` after loading the necessary data, but some routes use the same component - for example `/user` and `/user/edit` might both use the User component, but `/user/edit` triggers a popup. The popup changes the title, and when it is closed, the title should go back to what it was on `/user`, but `ngOnInit` is not called because the component was never destroyed.

I'm wondering how to solve this properly. I will definitely be able to do it, but it will be a lot of code and it seems quite error prone. Is there a clean solution that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Create an Observable which emits a new value whenever your pop up get initialized or destroyed, And based on this value get your work done

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-privacy',
  templateUrl: './privacy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./privacy.component.scss']
})
export class PrivacyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private title: Title) {
    this.setMetaAndTitle();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setMetaAndTitle() {
    this.title.setTitle('Privacy - All you need to know');
  }

}
```

All you need is to import `Title` from `@angular/platform-browser` and use this as described

Comment: Added an edit to my question to make it clear that I'm already using `Title.setTitle()`. My question is more about how to do this without creating an error prone mess og spaghetti. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: can you show the code snippet for popup and how you are closing it?

Comment: Just imagine a popup which is shown if `x` is true, and `x` is toggled with a button on the parent component. When it's closed, `x` is set to false. The title is updated in the popups ngOnInit, but not updated back to the parents title when it's closed. I can find workarounds for this, but this is just 1 of I think many workarounds that I'll have to implement and I'm wondering if there's a better way that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

try pass route parameters and make subscribe to queryParams ()

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(data => {})
```

or track changes to the route using router events